# Limit input to 0-100 value with HTML

Tags: html, input

I wonder if there is anyway to put a limit on an `input` element's value with HTML5?

```
<input type=number value=99> /valid
<input type=number value=101> /invalid
```

I'm not after JS fixes here.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-max

Comment: How hard is it to use the search? Like literally.

Comment: How hard is it to take the time to be as boring as you are :p?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `min` and `max` attributes:

```
<input type=number min=0 max=100>
```

Answer (score 1):

2 minutes of googling

[HTML5 Form validation](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/)

"The number and range input types also accept parameters for min, max and step. In most cases you can leave out step as it defaults to 1."

Example:

```
Age: <input type="number" size="6" name="age" min="18" max="99" value="21">
```

Comment: lol nice sarcasm tom... lol no need to say how much better you are than me at googling

Comment: :p no need to mention how long it took you to find it is all my point is :)

Comment: Just giving a hint where I found it!